# The Julia Language - JuMP package, unexpected model feasibility result using GLPK

Tags: glpk, julia-jump

I'm new to both the Julia Language and its optimization package JuMP. I'm trying to solve a really simple optimization problem, the objective is the minimization of the fixed costs for a facility location problem

```
o = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))

@variable(o, x[i = 1:size(candidates, 1)], Bin)       #creating variables for each possible location
@variable(o, ϑ[i = 1:size(demand, 2)] >= 0)           #creating one variable for each demand scenario (in this case only one scenario is considered)

@objective(o, Min, dot(x,cost_facility) * (1 + M) + sum(capacities .* x .* TH .* lab_cost_plant) + 1/size(demand,2) * sum(ϑ))

@constraint(o, 30000x[1] + 20000x[2] + 30000x[3] + 20000x[4] >= 1500.0)
@constraint(o, ϑ[1] + 1.6317502375004835e10x[1] + 1.0878334916669891e10x[2] + 1.6318862646433956e10x[3] >= 2.9076517866671824e9)

JuMP.optimize!(o)
st = MOI.get(o, MOI.TerminationStatus())
@info "Status $st"
```

And I get the following result:

```
┌ Info: Status INFEASIBLE
└ @ Main In[37]:3
```

I couldn't see why such a problem could be infesible, considering that those two constraints were the only ones present. So, I tried to modify them to understand what was wrong and it turned out that by substituting the second constraint with an equality constraint (and keeping everything else unchanged):

```
@constraint(o, ϑ[1] + 1.6317502375004835e10x[1] + 1.0878334916669891e10x[2] + 1.6318862646433956e10x[3] == 2.9076517866671824e9)
```

An optimal solution is found:

```
┌ Info: Status OPTIMAL
└ @ Main In[43]:3
```

I couldn't find any explanation for that, shouldn't the first problem be feasible too? Is there any mistake in the code? Thank you in advance for your help

```
 candidate_plant = ["Roma", "London", "Berlin", "Milano"]
 candidate_whs = ["Munich", "Glasgow","Madrid", "Lione"]
 capacity_plant = [30000, 20000, 30000, 20000]
 capacity_whs = [400000, 300000, 400000, 300000]
 cost_plant = [174739, 293932, 174739, 293932]
 cost_whs = [124739, 213932, 124739, 213932]
 demand = [10000; 10000; 10000]
 TH = 20
 M = 0.3
 lab_cost_plant = 8.64 

 candidates = vcat(candidate_plant, candidate_whs)
 capacities = vcat(capacity_plant, capacity_whs)
 cost_facility = vcat(cost_plant, cost_whs)
```

This is the input data used